# Need help with algebra portion of calculus finding slope of secant line

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

The example problem is: Given f(x) = $x^2$,find and simplify the slope of the secant line for a = 1 and h = any non-zero number.

The answer is as follows:

For a = 1 and h any non-zero number, the secant line goes through  (1, f(1)) = (1,1) and (1+h,f$(1+h))$ = $(1+h,(1+h)^2)$ and its slope is

(1)$$\frac {f((1+h) - f(1)} {h} =$$

(2) $$\frac{(1+h)^2 - 1^2} {h} =$$

(3) $$\frac{1 + 2h + h^2 -1} {h} = $$

(4) $$\frac {h(2+h)} {h} = $$

(5) $$2 + h$$  where h != 0.

My question here is the algebra.  I do not understand how they got from step (2) to step (3) to step (4).  In the book step (2) is annotated as "square the binomial".  Step (3) is annotated as "combine like terms and and factor the numerator".  (Step (4) is annotated as "cancel" - that much I understand.

So can anyone walk me through steps 3 to 5?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From steps 2 to 3 they used:
$$(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2$$

From steps 3 to 4 they used $$1+2h+h^2-1=2h+h^2$$
then $$2h+h^2=h(2+h)$$

Comment: Ah, thank you!  I got roped into a calculus class but I haven't done algebra in decades so I am frantically trying to review the latter as I learn the former.  I haven't gotten that far into the review but that old chestnut jumped out at me as soon as I saw your answer.  Thanks much.

Comment: @NewtonFalls, you're welcome, glad to help.